# How to make Ember Cli Mirage to work with Ember Simple auth

Tags: javascript, ember.js, oauth-2.0, ember-simple-auth, ember-cli-mirage

For development and testing I want to use Ember CLi Mirage. I'm trying to get it to work with simple auth and oauth2. How do I have to set up Mirage to work with a session token?

This is what I'm doing so far:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
        authenticate() {
            var data = this.getProperties('username', 'password');
            this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:oauth2-password-grant', data);
        }
    }

});
```

And in mirage I'm not sure how to set up my token route:

```
this.post('/token');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom work like this, [pass a function](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/routes/#function-handler) in as the second parameter to your route definition:

```
this.post('/token', function(db, request) {
  // generate a token

  return {
    token: token
  };
});
```

I'd have to know more about your backend to offer more specific guidance, but this is the general idea. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is a good hint. The backend will probably be done with sails and waterlock. I haven't completely figured out the backend side yet.

Comment: On a page reload is the page supposed to go back to the login window? How do I set up Mirage to keep the logged in state?

Comment: currently mirage is instantiated in an ember initializer so, if you reboot your ember session you reboot your mirage server. so, i'm not sure if this is possible :/ perhaps open an issue about it and we can discuss further

Answer (score 2):

I use the following in my tests:

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import { authenticateSession } from 'app-name/tests/helpers/ember-simple-auth'; 
import moduleForAcceptance from 'app-name/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | whatever');

test('visiting /subpage-that-requires-authentication', function(assert) {

  authenticateSession(this.application);

  visit('subpage-that-requires-authentication');

  andThen(function() {

    assert.equal(currentURL(), 'subpage-that-requires-authentication');
  });
});
```